# What socket send/recv operations can run concurrently using Boost.Asio

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp, boost-asio

I am aware that one can run async_send and async_receive operations concurrently on TCP and UDP sockets. But what is the expected behavior in these situations:

1. calling two async_send operations concurrently on an UDP socket.
2. calling two async_receive operations concurrently on an UDP socket.
3. calling two async_send operations concurrently on a TCP socket.
4. calling two async_receive operations concurrently on a TCP socket.

I'm mainly interested in the first case; since UDP doesn't necessarily preserve the order of sent packets, I don't care much if they are sent in order different from the one async_send was invoked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same thing happens as would happen without Boost ASIO:

> calling two async_send operations concurrently on an UDP socket.

Both datagrams will be sent.

> calling two async_receive operations concurrently on an UDP socket.

It is arbitrary which operation will receive the next datagram, but both operations will behave normally.

> calling two async_send operations concurrently on a TCP socket.

The data may interleave unpredictably.

> calling two async_receive operations concurrently on a TCP socket.

The data may interleave unpredictably.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I hoped for. Since (as is implied from your answer) ASIO is aware of this kind of usage, the next question if I may is whether both, POSIX and Win sockets guarantee this behavior.

Comment: @PeterJankuliak I'm not sure they formally guarantee it, but this is reliable behavior on every implementation I'm aware of.