# Are those async_* functions of boost::asio lib executed parallelly by OS

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio

Recently I'm using boost::asio library, and have a question about those async_* functions.

Say I call multiple `boost::asio::async_write()` consecutively, is it possible that these `async_write()` functions executed parallelly by the underlying operating system even if io_service is run single-threadedly

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is it possible that these async_write() functions executed parallelly
>   by the underlying operating system

Yes, they are!
There are two types of asynchronous actions, CPU-bound tasks and IO-bound tasks.

CPU-bound tasks are tasks that involve only CPU-execution, like calculations, reading and writing data to the RAM, etc.

IO-Bound tasks are tasks that involve reading and writing to devices, like the Hard-disk (file IO) , network card (network IO) etc.

In order to asynchronously execute CPU-bound tasks you need multiple threads but IO is different. Asynchronous IO does not utilize threads to be parallel, it just queues a request to the relevant device (Hard-disk, networking card etc.) and moves on to execute another code, without waiting for the IO to finish.

So yes, asynchronous IO (given, for example, by boost **As**ynchronous **IO**) will still work in parallel even without multiple threads.

Comment: Just be careful when calling an [`async_` function on one object more than once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998899/what-socket-send-recv-operations-can-run-concurrently-using-boost-asio).